# How to get notified before OOM liller killing or memory low on linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

I'd like to get notifications from linux system when my application is using too much memory or system memory is low.I'v done some searching, some solution needs to patch kernel and watch on a file such as /dev/mem-notify.
Is there a standard system signal send to the application? I'm using GTK2.0, is there a GTK way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to run a script that looks for a low memory condition and alerts you. This article has a couple of decent scripts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/234292/warning-when-available-ram-approaches-zero

The code from that article would need to be modified a bit for whatever flavor of linux you are using (it assumes desktop ubuntu) but it's a useful starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Minimum available memory limit, MB
THRESHOLD=400

#Check time interval, sec
INTERVAL=30

while :
do

    free=$(free -m|awk '/^Mem:/{print $4}')
    buffers=$(free -m|awk '/^Mem:/{print $6}')
    cached=$(free -m|awk '/^Mem:/{print $7}')
    available=$(free -m | awk '/^-\/+/{print $4}')

    message="Free $free""MB"", buffers $buffers""MB"", cached $cached""MB"", available $available""MB"""

    if [ $available -lt $THRESHOLD ]
        then
        ### MODIFY THIS NOTIFICATION METHOD FOR YOUR OS 
        notify-send "Memory is running out!" "$message"
    fi

    echo $message

    sleep $INTERVAL

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent kernels does not send SIGTERM any more. Only SIGKILL is sent to the process. So, there is no way a trigger can be received from the kernel.

Comment: "Recent kernels does not send SIGTERM any more." You may want to give a specific version number instead of "recent" and a link to some authoritative source for that statement would help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be helpful: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html

> 13.4 Killing the Selected Process
>
> Once a task is selected, the list is walked again and each process
>   that shares the same mm_struct as the selected process (i.e. they are
>   threads) is sent a signal. If the process has CAP_SYS_RAWIO
>   capabilities, a SIGTERM is sent to give the process a chance of
>   exiting cleanly, otherwise a SIGKILL is sent.

It is possible to hook SIGTERM but not SIGKILL. Anyway if the OOM killer is running you have bigger problems.

Alternatively perhaps you could self-monitor the memory intensiveness of your application and quit if it gets too high.

Comment: This seems to mean that only a privileged process can get warned in advance that it's about to be OOM-killed. Pretty risky, this means all unprivileged processes are likely to experience data corruption from the OOM killer...